# How do I suppress T-SQL warnings when running a script SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, suppress-warnings

Is it possible to suppress warnings generated by T-SQL scripts? If so, how?

I know I can turn of the 'records affected' messages with

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

but is there an equivalent for warnings?
Eg:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

If I'm expecting these errors, it helps to sift the real errors from the chaff in a big script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

See [SET ANSI_WARNINGS {ON | OFF}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx)

Comment: While this answer is perfectly valid I want to add something: Setting ANSI_WARNINGS has lots of other behavior changes and disables certain features. Changing it to a nonstandard value is likely to break stuff in other places. I would consider it to be bad practice to use it.

Comment: Please add a little more flesh to your link-only answer. Thanks.

Comment: So is it on or off? (hint: it's `off`) a binary answer is not an answer. I'm not sure how a weblink got upvoted 43 times.