# Suppress T-SQL warnings generated by IGNORE_DUP_KEY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, suppress-warnings

Is there a way to suppress warnings generated by inserting duplicate keys on indexes with IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON?  The warning it gives is "Duplicate key was ignored."

I am investigating using this option with a table variable for performance reasons, but it generates a lot of warning messages.  This can be a problem since I log the output of my script to a text file, and I don't want the log file to fill up with hundreds of lines of this warning over and over.

The warnings can be reproduced with the following script.  Note: this is not my actual script, but merely an example for illustration purposes.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

DECLARE @data TABLE (x int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
DECLARE @i int;

SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @data (x) VALUES (@i);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;

DECLARE @test TABLE (x int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON));
SET @i = 2;
WHILE @i <= 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @test (x) SELECT x FROM @data WHERE (x % @i) = 0 AND x > @i
    SET @i = (SELECT MIN(x) FROM @data d WHERE x > @i
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @test t WHERE t.x=d.x));
END;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @test;
```

This is similar to [How do I suppress T-SQL warnings when running a script SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280508/how-do-i-suppress-t-sql-warnings-when-running-a-script-sql-server-2005), but the solution there does not work in this case.  I have also seen suggestions for using TRY...CATCH, but that does not work either: it appears you can't catch warnings.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2017 and later, there is an option for this:

```
DECLARE @test table 
(
    x int NOT NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        WITH 
        (
            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON
                (SUPPRESS_MESSAGES = ON)
        )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you removed the "WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)" option from the table declaration and instead wrapped your INSERT statement using a try/catch block. See the example below:

```
BEGIN TRY 
  INSERT INTO @test (x) SELECT x FROM @data WHERE (x % @i) = 0 AND x > @i 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF NOT (ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627 AND ERROR_SEVERITY() = 14)
    PRINT 'Real error occurred.'
END CATCH
```

Comment: That doesn't have the same behavior.  Without IGNORE_DUP_KEY, a single error causes the entire transaction to fail.  So, for example, if I'm trying to insert 4, 13, and 57, if 4 is already in the table then neither 13 nor 57 will be inserted.  With IGNORE_DUP_KEY on, both 13 and 57 will be inserted, but 4 will not be inserted a second time.