# COUNT and WHERE statements query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

At the moment I have this

```
SELECT
    COUNT (enrollment_id) AS enrollments,
    COUNT (result) AS 
    MAX (result) AS highest_result,
    AVG (result) AS average_result,
    MIN (period_code) AS earliest_enrollment    
FROM 
    enrollment
WHERE
result IS NULL
```

What I want to have is the number of enrollments in total, which is what `COUNT(enrollment_id)` is for. I then want to count the number of `NULL` values in the results column to obtain a column for `unfinalised_enrollments`.

Will the `WHERE` clause at the bottom affect the other `SELECT` statements that use the results column? If so how do I make it so that I can COUNT just the number of `NULL` values in the results column and display it in a column called `unfinalised_enrollment`.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just perform 2 queries. There is absolutely no reason to try to fit everything in one query

Comment: It's actually a question and the one query has to include both so that it displays as one table. I've pretty much got everything it's just this one little hiccup.

Comment: if you wish - you could use something like `SUM(result IS NULL)` - this would count amount of null values

Comment: @LewisFitch: What database and version are you using?

Comment: @Mark Byers: yep, that's why I didn't put it as an answer

Comment: Using microsoft SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (enrollment_id) AS enrollments,
    SUM (CASE WHEN result IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS null_results,
    MAX (result) AS highest_result,
    AVG (result) AS average_result,
    MIN (period_code) AS earliest_enrollment    
FROM enrollment
```

Comment: 1. `COUNT` and `MIN (period_code)` results may be affected (very likely) 2. `AVG (result)` - would it be affected as well? (haven't tried to perform `AVG` for null-contained values)

Comment: this works for oracle but how about sql server 2008 as the question?

Comment: @shareef: `CASE` is ANSI SQL operator

Comment: @shareef: that's standard SQL and should work just fine for SQL Server (or any other SQL database)

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, the results will be affected. The query that the OP wrote will likely give the wrong result because some rows won't be included in the counts and no rows will be included in the average. The query I posted should work.

Comment: Everything works. Will test later properly, but for now that has fixed my problem, thanks a bunch!

Comment: On SQL Server, `AVG(result)` gives a warning which can [easily be disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280508/how-do-i-suppress-t-sql-warnings-when-running-a-script-sql-server-2005).

Comment: @Mark Byers +1 for fast thinking

Comment: @shareef: it's not a fast thinking at all - it's a **very common** pattern *every* DBA/programmer knows

Answer (score 0):

This one should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (enrollment_id) AS enrollments,
    ( SELECT COUNT (result) FROM enrollment WHERE result IS NULL ) AS unfinalised_enrollment,
    MAX (result) AS highest_result,
    AVG (result) AS average_result,
    MIN (period_code) AS earliest_enrollment    
FROM 
    enrollment;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (enrollment_id) AS enrollments,
    Count(*) - Count(result) AS null_results,
    MAX (result) AS highest_result,
    AVG (result) AS average_result,
    MIN (period_code) AS earliest_enrollment    
FROM enrollment
```

`Count(*)` will count the total number of rows, Count(result)`enter code here` will count the total number of rows where result is not null